# Запись std::list в бинарный файл

Tags: c++

Можете на примере показать как записать list в бинарный файл.Потому что запись как обычной переменной не прокатывает.Выдает error C3867

```
class A abstract
 {
  public:
   int field1=10;
 };
class B : public A
 {
  public:
   string field 2="text";
 }
class Database
 {
  list <A*> Base;
 public:
 const list<A* > getListTechnic()
 {
    return Base;
 }     
};
int main()
{
  Database base;
  ofstream file("f.bin",ios::binary);
  if(file.is_open())
    f.write((char*)&base,sizeof(base));//не работает
}
```

Comment: а что у вас в list? Цифры, строки, объекты, кони? От этого какбы зависит способ записи

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Указатели на базовый класс

Comment: ну вообще отлично. И что вы думаете вам ответят, если никто не вкурсе что содержится в объектах класса и что нужно запись?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch щя минуту

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Примерно так упрощенно выглядит

Comment: 1) используйте цикл для записи - у вас в вашем base находится список элементов для записи, так что итерируйтесь по списку. 2) в каждой итерации берете указатели на переменные, находящиеся в обхекте вашего класса(!), а не на сам объект, приводите их к char * и записываете в соответствии с размером. 3) для записи строк берете &string[0] и приводите к char *, а размер берете из string.size(). Вроде все что нужно

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch спасибо пока писал уже разобрался

Comment: Более интересный вопрос - как прочитать такой список из файла.